# How to preserve current image in mvc 5 edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I was trying an MVC 5 edit code with a file upload. I want to update my details except my image. But when I did the coding and tried it, my image field updated to 'null'. How to solve this else condition where no image was selected? i.e., I don't want to update my image, but other fields.

Comment: Please check [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people understanding your problem: add relevant code, errors if any (it seems you don't have error), etc

Answer (score 0):

If you use sql and update image path in sql then write down like this.

```
UPDATE 
    tblName
SET
 Colname=@param,
 ImageColumn = ISNULL(@paramimg,ImageColumn)
Where id =@Id
```

Comment: if(image1!=null)
            {
                string imagename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image1.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/image/" + imagename);
                image1.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                cg.image = imagename;
                db.Entry(cg).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                 db.Entry(cg).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }    //I use this code

Comment: Please save image name in hidden field. after update query.